# usb stick's broken after badblock with -w option

Tags: linux, usb, memory, hard-drive-failure, bad-blocks

I have two usb sticks with 8Gb and 128Gb size. For different reasons, I pass badblocks with -svw option, and now both sticks are totally damaged. Every time I want to write on it I have the same error: *read only while setting up superblock, read only while trying to open /dev/sdc* , etc...

I tried with **hdparm -r0 /dev/sdX** .....but next time I tried to write (fdisk, parted, etc...), it put read only again and again.

Both with message "**SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:**" when launch hdparm

Both with Model Serial Number and more data lost:

```
ATAPI ACS-IT8 device, with removable media
    Model Number:       ����������������������������������������
    Serial Number:      ��������������������
    Firmware Revision:  ��������
    Media Serial Num:   ����������������������������������������
    Media Manufacturer: ��������������������
    Transport:          0xaaaa; Revision: 0xaaaa
```

Transport and revision has the same code '0xaa' that badblocks use to write on first pass.

Used gparted, Disk Utility, fdisk, etc... no solution.

I use Windows too (rufus, hp tool, native utils from windows like diskpart) ... and no solution.

```
# badblocks -o 128gigasbadblocks.txt -wvs /dev/sdc
Checking for bad blocks in read-write mode
From block 0 to 123481087
Testing with pattern 0xaa: done                                                 
Reading and comparing: done                                                 
Testing with pattern 0x55: done                                                 
Reading and comparing: done                                                 
Testing with pattern 0xff: done                                                 
Reading and comparing: done                                                 
Testing with pattern 0x00: done                                                 
Reading and comparing: done                                                 
Pass completed, 123481088 bad blocks found. (320/123480768/0 errors)


# mkfs.ext3 -b 1024 -l /root/128gigasbadblocks.txt /dev/sdd
mke2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Creating filesystem with 123481088 1k blocks and 7717888 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 8e6ccb8b-1dc7-4108-af2a-b8fddc21e42e
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    8193, 24577, 40961, 57345, 73729, 204801, 221185, 401409, 663553, 
    1024001, 1990657, 2809857, 5120001, 5971969, 17915905, 19668993, 
    25600001, 53747713

Bad block 0 out of range; ignored.
Block 1 in primary superblock/group descriptor area bad.
Blocks 1 through 474 must be good in order to build a filesystem.
Aborting....
```

The same with the other stick. Both broken at diferents computer, but both with same software: badblocks.

I can't believe that, after use badblocks, usb sticks are completly broken (hardware level). I think there must be a software solution.

How can I a recover the sticks to use it again?.

Comment: Have you tried fixing formatting with Linux disk tools, e.g. Ubuntu Disk Utility?

Comment: I would suggest sticking these into a windows box or mac and see what either of those say (especially windows).

Comment: Used gparted, Disk Utility (it's not from Ubuntu, it's from GNU), fdisk, etc... no solution.

Comment: I use Windows too (rufus, hp tool, native utils from windows like diskpart) ... no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Both drives are dead. You'll have to replace them.

The fact that model data are lost tells us that controllers in the drives have malfunctioned and overwritten some internal memory or entered a failure mode due to memory chip failure. Unfortunately it's not unheard of, especially for flash drives.